# In VS Code, How to configure / bind `ctrl` + `left-click` to a single key

Tags: visual-studio-code, key-bindings, vscode-keybinding

I am using a gaming mouse with 4 keys. I want to configure my `mouse-button 4` to do the same task as `ctrl + left-click` does ( go to function definition )

I am using ubuntu 20.04 OS. I tried to find the solution on google but did not get any proper solution. I tried to find extensions on vs code but nothing worked for me.

Kindly Help me out. I really appreciate any help someone can provide.